# Multiple providers on terraform module running

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a few accounts on AWS. Now I want to have one module to be running on all of them.

For this I have prepared the terraform.tf file on my root

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc1"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC1:role/MyRoleAcc1"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc2"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC2:role/MyRoleAcc2"
  }
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.14.0"
    }
  }
}

module "ssm-paramater-module" {
  source = "./ssm_parameter/"

  providers = {
    aws.acc1 = aws.acc1
    aws.acc2 = aws.acc2
  }

}
```

But have a problem

> Warning: Provider aws.acc1 is undefined
> │
> on terraform.tf line 34, in module "ssm-paramater-module":
> 34:     aws.acc1 = aws.acc1
> │
> Module module.ssm-paramater-module does not declare a provider named aws.acc1.
> If you wish to specify a provider configuration for the module, add an entry for aws.acc1 in the required_providers block within the module.
> ╵
> ╷
> Warning: Provider aws.acc2 is undefined
> │
> on terraform.tf line 35, in module "ssm-paramater-module":
> 35:     aws.acc2 = aws.acc2
> │
> Module module.ssm-paramater-module does not declare a provider named aws.acc2.
> If you wish to specify a provider configuration for the module, add an entry for aws.acc2 in the required_providers block within the module.

How correct workaround this?
Because if I will do single provider like

```
module "ssm-paramater-module" {
    providers = {
         aws = aws.acc1
    }
    source = "./ssm_parameter/"
}
```

It works well.

The module like itself I want to implement is just a simple SSM parameter :

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you have to have `configuration_aliases` defined in the module. In your example that would be:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws.acc1, aws.acc2 ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#provider-aliases-within-modules).

Comment: Tried to implement it, but the problem still exists :(

Comment: Then you'll have to add module code to the question.

Comment: Add to question, but there is nothing. Just default TF SSM template

Comment: So the error remains the same even if you add this block of code to the SSM module?

Comment: sorry didn't get that it should be on module. That helps and warning is gone. But.... now something interesting. When I implemented it, it apply this SSM only on master account, not on acc1 or acc2 using which, it should assume the role :)

Comment: Then you just have to use an alias in the resource because with verified providers if you don't specify the alias it will use the default aws provider.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to set this up, and neither is necessarily "correct", just depends on what abstraction you're intending to provide with this module.

---

The first option is that each call to your module works only with one AWS provider configuration, and then you call the module multiple times and send a different provider configuration to each one:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.14.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc1"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC1:role/MyRoleAcc1"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc2"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC2:role/MyRoleAcc2"
  }
}

module "ssm_parameter_acc1" {
  source = "./ssm_parameter/"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.acc1
  }
}

module "ssm_parameter_acc1" {
  source = "./ssm_parameter/"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.acc2
  }
}
```

The `providers` argument in each `module` block tells Terraform which provider configuration to use as this module's default ("unaliased") provider configuration. Each module has its own independent view of all of the provider configurations, so the provider configuration address named just `aws` in the "ssm_parameter" module will refer to the same provider configuration as `aws.acc1` or `aws.acc2` in the root module, depending on which of the two module calls you're looking at.

---

The other way to set this up is for the shared module to itself be aware of multiple AWS provider configurations.

This will require you to change the contents of the child module to declare that it expects multiple additional (non-default, non-aliased) provider configurations, like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"

      configuration_aliases = [ aws.acc1, aws.acc2 ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo_acc1" {
  provider = aws.acc1

  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo_acc2" {
  provider = aws.acc2

  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}
```

Notice that now the `resource "aws_ssm_parameter"` blocks include explicit `provider` arguments. If you don't specify `provider` here then Terraform defaults to `provider = aws`, but the `configuration_aliases` argument in the `required_providers` block does not declare a default (unaliased) `aws` configuration, so now you must explicitly assign each resource to one of your additional (aliased) provider configurations.

When you call this module from your root module, the `module` block must pass in *both* of the provider configurations, like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.14.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc1"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC1:role/MyRoleAcc1"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acc2"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::ACC2:role/MyRoleAcc2"
  }
}

module "ssm_parameter" {
  source = "./ssm_parameter/"

  providers = {
    aws.acc1 = aws.acc1
    aws.acc2 = aws.acc2
  }
}
```

---

Which of the above to choose is a question of separation of concerns: which of these two modules is the one responsible for dealing with the fact that there are two accounts?

The first example above is the more common because describing a set of objects that should exist in *one* AWS account or region is often a nice abstraction boundary, and then the calling module can call that module as many times as necessary to create similar objects across multiple accounts or regions.

However, the second example would also be valid if there being two AWS accounts is just an inherent part of your architecture that this child module needs to deal with. One reason why I might choose the second option is if the module is responsible for writing different values into each account, and the details of which values go into which account are part of this module's own abstraction.